# Stop body from moving. Chipmunk on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, chipmunk

I have a cpBody with single cpShape that floats in my scene colliding with other bodies et c. How can I easily make this body stay in one place and act kind like a static obstacle staying in one place so it's not longer moving but still colliding with other bodies.

I just want to stop body from moving when user taps on it. That's why I'm asking. I'm not an expert in Chipmunk but I think it must be easy.

Comment: I'm not using Chipmunks, but there should be an option to specify static body somewhere.

Comment: You can add static body, not convert dynamic one to static. I don't want to remove the dynamic body and then add the static body with same parameters. I'm just asking cause maybe there is a quick way of doing this that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `cpBodySetMass` to INFINITY, and force the object to sleep with `cpBodySleep`. This is how a static object is implemented internally (at least about the mass).

**EDIT**

I am not sure whether you need to call `cpBodySleep` after this or not, but I don't think it hurts to call.

Modify `cpBody.h` and put `#define CP_ALLOW_PRIVATE_ACCESS 1` at the beginning. Then from `cpBody*`, access `->node.idleTime` and set it to INFINITY.

**EDIT 2**

The above solution is a working solution, but not very good in term of SE practice. It is better to define a function that makes the object static or dynamic so that you can call without disabling private property for the whole object.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. But what about the gravity then. My objects starts to fall because I've got a gravity in my space?

Comment: @RafałSroka: Do you want a solution that modifies the source code? The modification is not much anyway.

Comment: Well, I don't want to modify the chipmunk's code. Is there any option to do it without altering chipmunk's code.

Comment: @RafałSroka: I'm afraid there is no other options (unless I overlook some API). The `node` member of `cpBody` is declared private, and I see node.idleTime being set to INFINITY in the initialization code (`cpBody.cpp`) for static object.

Answer (score 5):

The way you'd do this with the public API is to remove the body and shape from the space. Create a new static body with the same position/rotation as the old dynamic body. Use cpShapeSetBody() to change the body to the new static one, and then readd the shape to the space.

Comment: Slembcke made Chipmunk, so hopefully this solution should work. :-)  +1